# Custom List Definitions - Remove the standard create item menu option

Tags: list, content-type, ribbon, list-definition

I'm creating a custom list definition in SharePoint 2010 by following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728096.aspx).

It works well but I need to remove the default create list item option and only keep that for Bug Item.

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually: Go to the list settings and under the "Content Types"-section you can find the button
"Change new button order and default content type ", click there and deselect the checkbox for "Item" to make it invisible. Deleting this is not possible, but you can hide it for the users...

Programming: Put an eventhandler on the list, when it's created remove the contenttype (= make invisible)